# When React-Native generates an ios and android folder, what part can I change?

Tags: react-native

So currently, I'm working on moving my React Native project outside of Expo and using regular React Native.

As I expect, it generates an ios and Android folder. However, there are about 5k+ worth of files and folders being generated here.

I know that React Native allows you to write your hybrid code in JSX which generates native code in your android and ios folder. You can also write custom native code in the android and ios folders.

My question, how do I know what exactly React Native generates in those folders and which of those files won't be clobbered if I make changes to it?

Comment: When you do changes in RN code, you should not concern much about native code. It should not affect anything any binaries unless the module/logic you are implementing is nit supported by native code. Both Android and iOS contain RN native code and its build files for generating `ipa` and `apk`.

Comment: If you make any changes into native code or create new folders ec, this does not affect the build result. You can add your own files and create own file tree in each native folder individually.

Comment: @parohy - ok so if i make changes to existing files, how do I know what will and will not get clobbered when i make changes to my react native JS files?

Comment: Are you referring to some specific files?

Comment: @parohy : not specifically. But I guess take this library for instance (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions), it asks you to edit the androidmanifest.xml and plist.info files. So does that mean that file isn't automatically generated and I can edit it? That's the info I'm trying to find, what is generated by react-native and what is editable.

Comment: both listed files can be edited. both files provide an app information such as permission list of activities ec. These files expect to be edited manually during development on both native platforms. If somethings goes wrong it will throw an error during compilation. And you can always use git and make progress commits so you can roll back any time.